# Cypress Test fails with ForgeRock Authorization (401 Unauthorized) when putting in correct Credentials?

Tags: authentication, cypress, forgerock

[image]

When I visit my app, I get redirected to ForgeRock AM to put in my credentials. This works outside of Cypress (Browser: Electron 100) when I log in manually and run my server on localhost.
Did anyone experience a similar situation with Cypress and ForgeRock?
I also don't know what code snippet or other information would help you, tell me and I will add it. :)

Comment: Do you have an active session in another or the same realm?

Comment: Yeah, its active in a whole company.